# Springboot + Thymeleaf Whitelabel error page when trying to render simple html file at root URL

Tags: spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I have been trying to set up a springboot project, with thymeleaf and postgres, but when trying to display my test.html page on the root URL for localhost:8090 it doesn't work.

My project structure: https://gyazo.com/860b558f0526fbd1dfd61309ab6eaad6

My home controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showCodeEditor() {
        return "test"; // The name of your HTML template (without the ".html" extension)
    }
}
```

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a test page</h1>
<p>If you see this, the template setup is working.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/coder
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.port = 8090
server.error.include-message=always
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
```

Output upon running program: https://gyazo.com/c6edad31cac42822460f781d10b7e5cb

This is whats displayed on localhost:8090

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 25 18:08:28 BST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: You added many details on your question and left out the most important. The error stacktrace. Please edit it and add this information.

Comment: I added the output that displays when I run the program, but I don't get any errors in the console

Comment: there is a bunch of mismatches on your project, not that this is the cause but it would be good to fix them. Your pom file is referencing two java versions (17, 19) and your screen shot shows it is running on java 20. stick to only one. Then configure your properties file the log level to debug. It doesn't look like your application is seeing the mapped path (endpoints/controllers), hence the 404 error (endpoint doesn't exist). start with that